# How to serve mock files from ionic-lab and how to set ionic config json

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-cli

I've been using Angular for a while, but I'm new to Ionic. Recently, I started a project.

[image: My project folder is as follows]

I added a folder named `mocks` which holds some mock json files. I want to be able to retrieve these files from `http://localhost:8100/mocks/my-mock-data.json` which I could not have done.

Coming from angular-cli, I thought I should add `mocks` folder to some config so that ionic-lab can serve files from this folder.

In `.angular-cli.json`, you would add your custom folders to `apps[0].assets` array, so angular-cli can serve them. I thought it would be similar in ionic too, so I tried to add my `mocks` folder to `ionic.config.json`. However, I could not find how to (I'm not even sure this is the right place to add it)

Then, I tried to find a schema for `ionic.config.json` so that I can get some intellisense on VsCode and maybe I can find the right config myself. However, I could not find schema for `ionic.config.json` as well.

Then, I googled for how to set ionic configs. I came across [their website](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/config/set/)
They give some examples but not the full list.

```
Input       Description
property    The property name you wish to set
value       The new value of the given property
```

So, my questions are

1. How can I serve some mock files from ionic-lab?
2. What are the full set of properties and corresponding values in `ionic.config.json`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot serve files like that in ionic. Note that ionic simply combines everything in one `main.js` file, and assets are bundled separately.
When `ionic serve` or `ionic cordova run` are invoked, it ultimately calls an NPM script. These npm scripts call the `@ionic/app-scripts` library to execute the build process.

To use dummy data, you can simply place dummy data in any folder inside `src > assets` folder. Lets say you put it in `src > assets > example_data` folder as `json` file. Note that you can also save these files with `services` or `pages`.

Now, a service in say `dummydata-service.ts` under `src > providers` can reference it for test usage like

```
GetDummyData(): Promise<any> {
  return this.http.get('./assets/example_data/dummyData.json')
   .toPromise()
   .then(response => {return response.json()})
   .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

On the point of `ionic.config.json`, it is not analogous to `.angular-cli.json`.
This is an Ionic project config file which stores configuration values consumed by certain ionic.io services. Important keys being `app_id`, `name`, `typescript`.

Comment: So, it has some config hidden inside for assets folder. It feels like I should be able to add another folder. However it is not that important. About `ionic.config.json`, I know it is different than `.angular-cli.json`. ı just want to know which properties I can set in `ionic.config`. I could not find the full list.

Comment: Ionic.config stores project information. When you use ionic commands like `link`, `login`, etc. (refer https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands.html) then the properties used by ionic.io services get stored here. You would never need to edit them unless you plan on changing ionic service parameters.
This might interest you: http://legacy.docs.ionic.io/docs/io-config

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Do accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: It did not fully answer my question. I still don't know how to configure `ionic.config.json` I mean what properties it has and how to set them.

Comment: It is mainly required by Ionic Services offered by Ionic Pro. In order to work with these services from cli, the framework requires certain parameters for the app, which are stored in the `ionic.config.json`. These parameters include `name`, `app_id`, `v2`, and `typescript`. They get configured when you call any ionic command that requires usage of (now called) Ionic Pro Services. Try calling `ionic login` followed by `ionic link` from cli.